# Write igraph VertexClustering object to file (python)

Tags: python, csv, igraph

I'd like to read an edge list from a csv file, cluster it in python using igraph and `community_leiden`, and then write the clustering to a file for analysis in R. **How do I accomplish the last step - writing the clusters to a file?** Afaik the clusters are a VertexClustering object in Python.

The only info I need to write from `clusters` are which nodes are co-clustered. I can see this information when I do `print(clusters)`.

My code:

```
import igraph as ig

# read network
network = ig.Graph.Read_Ncol("edge_list.csv", directed=False)

# leiden (community_leiden)
clusters = network.community_leiden(resolution_parameter = 1.0)

# write clusters
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Though it is not a tested solution I have recently played with leidenalg package based on igraph. Each partition found by the 8 types of modularity routines is a class inheriting every aspect of igraph.cluster , hence its attributes should be similar.

TLDR; cluster.merbership should return you a list of the membership or cluster  that each node belongs to. You may prefer it as a partition dictionary so this may help

```py
membersof=cluster.membership
partitiond={i: member for i,member in enumerate(membersof) }
```